# Centralize with includegraphics

Tags: beamer, tikz-node, includegraphics

I'm having trouble with the beamer. I want to put a background image. The image is not too large, so I can not put the size of the page so it is not distorted. The problem is that using `scale=1`, I cannot centralize it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

 \usetheme{Ilmenau}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz\node[opacity=0.3]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{logo_ufrrj(1).png}};}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your image relative to the centre of the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[opacity=0.3] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made it. Just the same command, I only changed the includegraphics, but the image disappeared. Can it be conflicting with some pack?

Comment: I got it. I had erased the last space before de last } unintentionally